# Word add-in Error Code 13004

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, add-in, office-js, office-addins

Just want to ask for help in this error, seems like there is little documentation about this error. I created a Word add-in that utilizes MS Graph, when I deployed it through Azure App Service and run the add-in in Word. It throws this error:
Error code: 13004
Name: Invalid application resource Url provided.
Message: Invalid resource Url specified in the manifest.

Do note that I am using Azure's default app service URL for my add-in, which is something like https://yourappname.azurewebsite.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the documentation says about 13004:

Invalid Resource. The add-in manifest hasn’t been configured correctly. Update the manifest. For more information, see Validate and troubleshoot issues with your manifest. The most common problem is that the Resource element (in the WebApplicationInfo element) has a domain that does not match the domain of the add-in. Although the protocol part of the Resource value should be "api" not "https"; all other parts of the domain name (including port, if any) should be the same as for the add-in.

[Troubleshoot SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins)

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, just curious on this point: `all other parts of the domain name (including port, if any) should be the same as for the add-in`. So if I am deploying the same add-in to multiple environments, but it is hosted on different domains — does it mean that I need to create separate App Registrations in AD for each environment despite the security configuration being the same?

Comment: Yes. If you need to host the add-in's web app in more than one domain, then each of those is a distinct web app from AAD's point of view, so each must have its own registration. You will also need distinct add-in manifests for each domain (and not just because of SSO, there non-SSO-related URLs in the manifest too). Be sure that users who will be installing for domain A get the manifest for that domain and that users for domain B get the B manifest.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that, Rick. The need for multiple manifests (one per environment) is clear. It was the fact that I couldn't reuse the WebApplicationInfo node across the manifests that appeared counterintuitive (just from the common sense standpoint, there must be underlying reasons I don't understand).