# Outlook OSF.DDA.Error Invalid Resource Url Code: 13004

Tags: typescript, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to implement an addin for Outlook. Suddenly I get the following error when I try to retrieve data from my backend:

```
OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'Ungültige Anwendungsressourcen-URL angegeben.', message: 'Ungültige Ressourcen-URL im Manifest angegeben.', code: 13004}
```

(Translates to 'Invalid Resource URL given')
After some research I found:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins which seemed promising and [Word add-in Error Code 13004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962387/word-add-in-error-code-13004) (which is a copy of the dodumentation link before). So I changed my manifest urls to api:// instead of https:// (which worked fine before).
Afterwards I ran the validation, expecting some errors to occur:
(I ran the validation before changing to api://, which yielded the same results.)

```
npm run validate

> office-addin-taskpane-react@0.0.1 validate D:\Source\ProjectName.Client
> office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml

The manifest is not valid.


Error # 1: 
High Resolution Icon URL Unreachable: Unable to retrieve an image from the high resolution icon URL.
  - Details: The HighResolutionIconURL supplied in the app manifest is not reachable, HighResolutionIconURL : https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png.

Error # 2: 
Icon URL Unreachable: Unable to retrieve an image from the icon URL.
  - Details: The IconURL supplied in the app manifest is not reachable, IconURL : https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png.

Additional information: 
Package Type Identified: Package of your add-in was parsed successfully.

Correct Package: Your package matches the submission type.

Valid Manifest Schema: Your manifest does adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Add-in manifests.

Manifest Version Correct Structure: The manifest version number has the correct structure for the platform that it supports.

Manifest Version Correct Value: The manifest version number is greater or equal to 1.0.

Manifest ID Valid Prefix: The product ID in the manifest has a valid prefix
  - Details: [ProductId]

Manifest ID Correct Structure: The structure of the product ID is correct.
  - Details: [ProductId]

Desktop Source Location Present: A desktop or default source location URL is found.

Secure Desktop Source Location: The manifest desktop source location URLs use HTTPS.

Supported Office Identified: Supported Office products were successfully determined.

Support URL Present: The manifest support URL is present.
  - Details: https://localhost:3000/help

Valid Support URL: The manifest support URL is valid.

High Resolution Icon Present: A high resolution icon element was expected and is present.
  - Details: https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png

Supported High Resolution Icon URL File Extension: The manifest high resolution icon URL has a valid image file extension.
  - Details: png

Secure High Resolution Icon URL: The manifest high resolution icon URL uses HTTPS.
  - Details: https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png

Icon Present: A icon element was expected and is present.
  - Details: https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png

Supported Icon URL File Extension: The manifest icon URL has a valid image file extension.
  - Details: png

The manifest icon URL uses HTTPS.: Secure Icon URL
  - Details: https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png

WebApplicationInfo is identified: The structure of WebApplicationInfo is correct.

Acceptance Test Completed: Acceptance test service has finished checking provided add-in.
```

The only errors on the beginning are: 'Unable to retrieve an image from the icon URL', which I tried manually and they can be loaded. They are loaded by the addin, too. So there seems to be no issue.

So I decided to print out my parameters for my https request (using 'https' package) to see if I accidentally call another domain, than the listed one in the manifest. Like this:

```js
      console.log({
        path: path,
        method: method,
        host: process.env.WEB_SERVER_HOST + ":" + process.env.WEB_SERVER_PORT
      });
      // EDIT: the token is not returned so the error happens in 'getAccessToken'
      OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({
          forMSGraphAccess: true
        }).then(token => {
          const req = https.request({
              method: method,
              headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              host: process.env.WEB_SERVER_HOST,
              port: process.env.WEB_SERVER_PORT,
              path: path, 
          }, (res) => {
          let data = "";
          res.on('data', (d) => {
            data += d;
          });
          res.on('end', () => {
            if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {
              if (!data) {
                  cb(null);
                  return; 
              }
              let jsonRes = JSON.parse(data);
              if (jsonRes) {
                  cb(jsonRes);
              }
            } else {
              err({
                name: res.statusCode.toString(),
                message: data, 
                stack: ""
              });
            }
          });
        });
        req.on('error', function(e) {
          if (err)
              err(e);
        });
        if (reqUpdate) {
          reqUpdate(req);
        }
        req.end();
      });
    }
```

And found there is an exact match to my URL in my manifest (except of the protocol https:// instead of api://).

EDIT: I checked my app registration, to see if the api path there is included in my AppDomains in my manifest. It is.

Any other things I could check to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please share the sample add-in with us to reproduce it?

Comment: I cannot upload the whole solution to stackoverflow. How should I share?

Comment: I've been using an external user, which is not created on the tenant with the App Registration. Anyways the user is allowed to access the tenant and the App is set to allow multi tenant access. The authentication works with a user from the App tenant, but not with externals.